# Kanban board plug-in for Trac

Tags: trac, plugins, kanban

Is there any plug-in/app for presenting/managing tickets from Trac bug tracking system on Kanban board? For example, I want to be able to change the status of Trac tickets by dragging-dropping them accross the board. I tried some standalone tools like AgileZen but but I couldn't find a way to integrate them with Trac.

Answer (score 20):

I've written two blog posts about [Trac and Kanban](http://mackeblog.blogspot.com/2011/01/trac-and-kanban.html) (and the new [T&K - Redux](http://mackeblog.blogspot.com/2011/09/trac-and-kanban-redux.html)) where we just fill a wiki-page with three columns of TracQuery-macros. There's some example source in there.

It's dead-simple (no drag and drop) but it works well for us. We use the GridFlow and BatchTicket plugins to quickly edit many tickets. The standard workflow is enough for daily tasks though.

The most recent version looks like this:

[image: trac wiki screenshot]

Note that by filtering on the age of the closed tickets column, you can also use this as a continous process, rather than per sprint/iteration/milestone.

Comment: thanks for sharing, the simplicity and power of the solution is really amazing

Answer (score 2):

The IttecoTracPlugin adds this, but it also adds a number of other features. There is no Trac plug-in that I am aware of that adds only a Kanban board.

http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/IttecoTracPlugin

Answer (score 1):

You could also try [Agilo for Scrum](http://www.agile42.com/cms/pages/agilo/) but of course it is tailored towards Scrum...

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer this very old post, bizarely enough with a solution provided by someone who has already replied - [CuriousCurmudgeon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/235145/curiouscurmudgeon) - his [WhiteboardPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/WhiteboardPlugin) (probably not written at the time of his post) does what you want.

Comment: I've tried that plugin. It was very beta at the time, and it doesn't seem to be actively developed.

Answer (score 1):

Also using wiki pages and macros:

https://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TracKanbanBoardMacro

Screenshot taken from there:
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use Cards Plugin for Trac.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a slightly locally modified version of WhiteBoardPlugin:

[image: Trac WhiteboardPlugin look]

It is mildly configurable and has some drag-and-drop functionality for tickets. It does the trick for our needs.

It can be found at:

https://trac-hacks.org/wiki/WhiteboardPlugin